# Issue building/linking C++ Libraries: XML++ and GLIB

Tags: c++, xml, dll, compiler-construction, linker

I am writing a c++ app for windows using code blocks IDE. I am interesting in using the following XML++ library: 
    http://libxmlplusplus.sourceforge.net/

It requires glibmm-2.4 and libxml2, as stated in the website. I  downloaded the source for these modules and included their headers/directories into my project. I used sample code from the examples/dom_parser directory from libxml++ as the main code.

However, I am having trouble "building" or "linking" the project. I am receiving "undefined reference" error messages. I am new to using .lib, .a, and .dll library files. Which specific files do I need to "link" to my project? I can't seem to find any of them in the downloaded zip files. Thank you. Here are the messages:

```
C:/Users/b/Desktop/workspace/xmlpp/main.cpp:44: undefined reference to `xmlpp::ContentNode::is_white_space() const'
C:/Users/b/Desktop/workspace/xmlpp/main.cpp:47: undefined reference to `xmlpp::Node::get_name() const'
C:/Users/b/Desktop/workspace/xmlpp/main.cpp:49: undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::empty() const'
C:/Users/b/Desktop/workspace/xmlpp/main.cpp:53: undefined reference to `xmlpp::Node::get_namespace_prefix() const'
C:/Users/b/Desktop/workspace/xmlpp/main.cpp:54: undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::empty() const'
```

Comment: You may find this an interesting read: [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)